# Sum each element in a python dictionary to find TCP Flags

Tags: python, dictionary, tcp

I have a dictionary with TCP flags:
I need to sum all the possibilities of two elements in this dictionary to find the corresponding value for the flag I have. Example:

```
flag = 24
di = {'urg': 32, 'ack': 16, 'psh': 8, 'rst': 4, 'syn': 2, 'fin': 1}
```

As we see the 24 corresponds to ack(16) + psh(8) = 24
How can I add sum elements to find and show the active flags?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bitwise operator AND - `&`.

For example:

```
flag = 24
di = {'urg': 32, 'ack': 16, 'psh': 8, 'rst': 4, 'syn': 2, 'fin': 1}

flags = [k for k, v in di.items() if v & flag]
print(flags)
```

Prints:

```
['ack', 'psh']
```

Answer (score 0):

## The sum of 2 Dictionary Items

If all you're looking for is `ack + psh` and you know the keys, then you the answer is

`answer = di['ack'] + di['psh']`

## The sums of all dictionary Items

If you really do want to get the sum of all dictionary items I would suggest a function that takes the dictionary and the flag, and returns a tuple of the keys of the dictionary that sum to the flag. Here's an example:

```py
def find_keys(di, flag):
  keys = di.keys()
  values = di.values()

  for n in range(len(keys)):
    for m in range(len(keys) - m)):
      if values[n] + values[m] == flag:
        return (keys[n], keys[m])

  # If none are found, it can return some error value:
  return (-1, -1)
```

In your code, you might run it with your given di, flag and get:

```py
keys = find_keys(di, flag)

print(keys)
print((di[keys[0]] + di[keys[1]]) == flag)
```

You should get:

```py
('ack', 'psh')
True
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help William! I'll check the code.

Comment: You should really not return something like (-1, -1) in case of an error. That would, among other drawbacks, force every piece of code using this function to check its return value before being able to use it. Raise an exception instead.